# dynamically inflate xml file on condition

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have one `EditText` and user enter number lets say 5. Now I want to inflate one xml file in 5 times.

My problem is xml file (which i inflate) have one Button Continue when user press it then I inflate it again.

For Example, I have arralist with questions and answers And they all are selected by user i store data in arraylist. Now I want to show each selected questions and answers one by one to user. So i decide to create one xml file which display questions and answer one by one when user click on next question.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to inflate one xml file in 5 times.

This is a bad design I must say, instead you can use `ListView(Vertically)` and inflate the layout row  or use `ViewPager(Horizontally)` for inflating your custom layout.

Comment: But i want to display only one question at a time when user click on next button he view second questions others are invisible..

Comment: so you can do that with ViewPager also.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `View` visible and invisible is a very bad design. From your question I assume that you want your users to enter the number of questions they want to answer in a quiz application.

Here, you wouldn't need 5 `TextView`s for 5 questions. You just need 5 questions in a `ArrayList` and just 1 `TextView` for question, 4 more `RadioButton`s for the choices. Then, whenever the user answers a question get a new question from your `ArrayList` and set its content to the `questionTextView` and `answerRadioButton`s.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply but how to programatically i do it for example when user 3 questions arralist have three values now display first question then second and at last third. I am so stuck for this same.

Comment: Have you used event listeners before? Such as the `OnClickListener`?